# React -JS eventhandler not updating component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a person component, with this source code.

```
const person = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p onClick={props.click}>
        I'm {props.name} and I am {props.age} years old!
      </p>
      <p>{props.children}</p>
      <input type="text" onChange={props.changed} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The idea is that I want the input text to update the name of the person component in my app.js file.

Here I have made a function called nameChangedHandler, to actually change the name (to start off I have only targeted the second object in my persons array).

```
nameChangedHandler = event => {
  this.setState({
    persons: [
      { name: "Kris", age: 22 },
      { name: event.target.value, age: 24 },
      { name: "Jenna", age: 29 }
    ]
  });
};
```

In my render method, I have added a variable called changed, where I'm calling the this.nameChangedHandler, to change the name of the second persons object

```
<Person
  name={this.state.persons[1].name}
  age={this.state.persons[1].age}
  click={this.switchNameHandler.bind(this, "Kris!")}
  changed={this.nameChangedHandler}
>
  My hobbies: Racing
</Person>;
```

Whenever I type some data into the input field, it is not changing the name of the person?

Comment: It works https://codesandbox.io/s/rjrz98n17n ,, Also note `const person` will be `const Person`

Comment: I figured out the issue, it was regarding naming my nameChangedHandler, wrong in my Text Editor. However, should I change the name person component to a capital K?

Comment: Yes. All Custom Components should be Capitalized first letter